# Maximize based on constraints

Tags: minizinc

3 Arrays f1,f2 and f3 have child elements (f1a,f1b) ; (f2a,f2b,f2c) ; (f3a,f3b,f3c,f3d) respectively.They are all bool variables

I have a combination of these child elements in a list with 2 columns . The first column gives an ID and second col has the combination of child elements as shown below

- row1 : 2345 | f1a , f2b
- row2 : 2345 | f1a,f2a,f3c
- row3 : 2346 | f2c, f3a
- row4 : 2347 | f1b, f2c
- .... ....

I need to choose one element of each of the arrays and form a selected array
if all elements of row are represented in selected array, I set 1 for that Row , else 0

So if selected array is  [ f1a,f2a,f3c] , then ( using the above list example)

- row1 is 0 ( as f2b is not in selected array)
- row2 is 1 as all elements of row are in selected list
- row3 is 0 as f2c and f3a is not in selected array
- row4 is 0 as f2c is not present in selected array

I need to choose the selected array so as to maximize the sum of  Row count (0+1+0+0 ...) for all Unique ID
for example if list is as shown below  and selected array is [f1a,f2b,f3c] , though both rows are set 1 ,
I would only take 1 from both the rows as ID is same in both rows

- row1 : 2345 | f1a , f2b
- row2 : 2345 | f1a,f2b,f3c

Any help is appreciated as I am new to Minizinc and struggling to formulate the constraint with Minizinc

Answer (score 1):

If your `row` variables are themselves also located in an array, then

```
solve maximize sum(row);
```

should set the activation of the rows to be the objective.

If you don't have them in an array you can still manually add them together to form an objective:

```
solve maximize row1 + row2 + row3 + row4;
```

I'm unsure if you were also asking about how the row activation itself works, but if a row only activates when all its elements are selected, then this would be enforced using a simple `forall` constraint:

```
constraint row1 = forall([...]);
```

Comment: Dekker , The Rows have a fixed combination of array elements and I suppose 'forall' would consider all possible combinations . I need to take the array elements from each row and create the constraint . And how about considering only Unique ID ?

Comment: Hi @MaheshSubramaniam, So the idea would be that you have a `forall` constraint for every row that you want to trigger. The idea is that when all elements are selected then the row will trigger. If two things have the same ID, aren't they exactly the same? In that case you can just add a constraint `a = b` to alias the two booleans.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally get it working with this code. Here row1 and row2 have same ID and similarly row 3 and row4 have another common ID

```
array[1..2] of var bool: f1 ;
array[1..2] of var bool: f1 ;
array[1..3] of var bool: f2 ;
array[1..4] of var bool: f3 ;
var bool: row1;
var bool: row2 ;
var bool: row3 ;
var bool: row4 ;
constraint sum(f1) == 1;  
constraint sum(f2) == 1;
constraint sum(f3) == 1;

constraint  row1 = forall ( [(f1[1])  ]  ) ;
constraint  row2 = forall ( [(f1[2]) , (f2[2]) , (f3[3]) ] );

constraint  row3 = forall ( [(f1[1]) , (f2[2]) , (f3[3]) ] ) ;
constraint  row4 = forall ( [(f1[2]) , (f2[1]) , (f3[4]) ] ) ;

var int: rown1 = bool2int(row1) ;
var int: rown2 = bool2int(row2) ;
var int: rown2a = max(rown1,rown2) ;

var int: rown3 = bool2int(row3) ;
var int: rown4 = bool2int(row4) ;
var int: rown4a = max( rown3,rown4) ;
var int: rown =  rown2a + rown4a ;

solve maximize rown;
```